# Carousel with partial in Ruby

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am rendering a partial in a loop, but now I want that partial to be a slider but it's not working. Here is my code to render a partial.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <% @authors.each_with_index do |author, index| %>
          <%= render 'author', author: author , index:index%>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

and in partial I did something like this

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 lt-padding-crusher item <%= 'active' if index == 0 %> " >
    <div class="author-card ">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 author-image lt-rt-padding-crusher">
        <%= image_tag(author.photo.url, :class=>'') %>
        <div class="author-name">
          <%= author.name %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
        <div class="author-desc">
          <%= author.bio %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my output:

[image]

Comment: "Not working" means what? Errors? Incorrect output? Computer catches on fire? Normally you do this with `render(partial: 'author', ...)` so it's possible the arguments are wrong. Always look at `log/development.log` for clues.

Comment: i am not using locals so its working fine

Comment: So it's working or it's not working? Be more specific, please.